# Use React Native variable to call method

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was wondering if there is a way to call methods for a react native component using a variable, its not something I have seen in the tutorials.
For example:

```
var navigate = <Navigator
    initialRoute={{ title: 'Awesome Scene', index: 0 }}
    renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
      <Text>Hello {route.title}!</Text>
    }
    style={{padding: 100}}
  />
```

How do I use the "navigate" variable to call a method like jumpForward().

Comment: Refer to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#additional-scenes, it passes the navigator in renderScene() to do the route functions such as pop and push

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the concept of refs. You can assign a ref to a react component and invoke its methods. Example

```
class MyApp extends Component {
  onButtonClicked{
    this.navRef.jumpForward();
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <Navigator
        ref={navRef => this.navRef = navRef}
        initialRoute={{ title: 'Awesome Scene', index: 0 }}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
        <Text>Hello {route.title}!</Text>
        }
       style={{padding: 100}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

More about refs at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Thanks agent_hunt, got it